Android kotlin Firebase SDK Authentication about?
even though I tried for a long time, I could not make the SDK link green (it did not approve). Normally, I can add data to the realtime database, but I want to use authentication for an application that can be accessed with e-mail and password. But when I use its codes, it does not register. Could it be because I can't establish the SDK connection?
[1


